# Should a line break be allowed inside a list of references if the lines are narrow?

Tags: biblatex, citing, line-breaking, two-column, multiple-citations

Let's say we have narrow columns and a list of references. We can try to squeeze the list into one of the two lines as

```
Typesetting errors are widespread [1, 2],
and they can affect readability.
```

or

```
Typesetting errors are widespread
[1, 2], and they can affect readability.
```

Alternatively, we can allow for a line break:

```
Typesetting errors are widespread [1,
2], and they can affect readability.
```

Which one should be preferred as a rule of thumb in narrow columns and why? In other words, should we allow for a line break after a separator in a list of references surrounded by brackets? Any rationale?

(For LaTeX with biblatex I get the first with

```
\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\,}
```

and the second with

```
\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\hskip.1666666666em plus.0833333333em minus.0833333333em\relax}
```

and I'm sure other packages offer similar possibilities.)

Comment: @cfr Even if it seems an opinion for you, proper typesetters often have rules, and not only “opinions”. After typesetting thousands of pages, you often know what to do pretty well.

Comment: @cfr Concerning „wide-spread“: exactly! Or even worse as “widesp-read“ if your hyphenation is broken.

Comment: @Clara It's unrelated to the question, i.e., irrelevant here. Anyhow, if you do this, you have to understand WHY. If you think about it, `xxx~\cite{yyy}` might make sense only if (1) “xxx [yyy]” is a single concept that you'd visually like to stick on a single line (say, `Smith's~paper~\cite{reference to paper}` or `tool~X~\cite{reference to X}`) or (2) “[yyy]” at the beginning of a new line would look like a sentence start, a list start, or a heading. Otherwise, keeping “xxx” and “[yyy]” intentionally together simply makes no extra sense compared to pairs of normal words in a usual sentence.

Comment: Or, replace "widespread" with "common" and see if you get a more pleasing line break...